# If I Accidentally Unsubscribe and Resubscribe From A YouTube Channel, Upon Checking When I Subscribed Will They See The New Date?

Tags: youtube

The title says it all. I'm wondering if resubscribing changes the subscription date. I was on Nintendo Switch YouTube, and accidentally clicked the “unsubscribe” icon. I resubbed within seconds and had to turn notifications back on. If they go to creator's studio and check when I subbed, will the new date be there or the old?